# Changing NSCursor for NSView above an NSTextView

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

Found a similar question to mine[(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816339/resetcursorrects-not-working-new-cursor-only-flashes-as-mouse-enters?rq=1),
but my issues seems to be a bit more associated with view hierarchy.

I have a NSTextView, then as sibling views, several other NSViews on top of it.

Similar to the question linked above, I setup a tracking area, and applied the cursor as such:

```
class CursorChangingView: NSView {
    override func updateTrackingAreas() {
        let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: 
    }

    override func cursorUpdate(event: NSEvent) {
        NSCursor.arrowCursor().set()
    }
}
```

It does seem to work when hovering, but immediately goes back to the [IBeam Cursor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCursor_Class/index.html), which is the default cursor for NSTextViews under this CursorChangingView.

Is this the proper way of applying changing the cursor when hovering over a certain NSView, and is the NSTextView under it overriding my overrriding?

Answer (score 6):

All you need is to subclass a custom view, override awakeFromNib method, add the custom tracking area for [.mouseMoved, .activeAlways] events: [NSTrackingArea Info](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTrackingArea_class/) there. There is no need to override `resetCursorRects` and/or `updateTrackingAreas`. All you need is to override mouseMoved method and set the desired cursor there:

Note about `discardCursorRects` method:

From the docs

> You need never invoke this method directly

**Xcode 9 • Swift 4**

```
import Cocoa

class CursorChangingView: NSView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        addTrackingArea(NSTrackingArea(rect: bounds, options: [.activeAlways, .mouseMoved], owner: self, userInfo: nil))

        wantsLayer = true
        layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.cyan.cgColor
        layer?.borderColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
        layer?.borderWidth = 1
    }

    @objc override func mouseMoved(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
        NSCursor.pointingHand.set()
    }
}
```

[Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dqu46urzct9fx2f/hoverCursor.zip?dl=1)

Comment: Did not work for me. If a textfield below the custom view has first responder, the cursor still changes back to the IBeam

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Leo Dabus for your answer,
but I managed to solve it, so I will post my answer too.

In my case, for some reason, `mouseEntered` and `mouseEntered` did not work at all.

So here is my code that finally got it to work:

```
class CursorChangingView: NSView {
    let trackingArea: NSTrackingArea?
    func setupTracking() {
        if self.trackingArea == nil {
            self.trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: self.bounds, options: NSTrackingAreaOptions.ActiveAlways | NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseMoved | NSTrackingAreaOptions.CursorUpdate | NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingAreaOptions.ActiveInActiveApp, owner: self, userInfo: nil)
            self.addTrackingArea(self.trackingArea!)
        }
    }

    override func updateTrackingAreas() {
        self.trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: self.bounds, options: NSTrackingAreaOptions.ActiveAlways | NSTrackingAreaOptions.CursorUpdate | NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingAreaOptions.ActiveInActiveApp, owner: self, userInfo: nil)
        self.addTrackingArea(self.trackingArea!)
    }

    override func resetCursorRects() {
        self.discardCursorRects()
        self.addCursorRect(self.bounds, cursor: NSCursor.arrowCursor())
    }

    override func mouseMoved(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        NSCursor.arrowCursor().set()
    }
}
```

It might be a little excessive, but worked, so will share this as my own solution.

Comment: In my case, this still flickers when the `CursorChangingView` is above an `NSTextView`. How did you get rid of that?

Comment: Also, the second time you're creating the tracking are, you're no longer tracking `.mouseMoved`

Answer (score 0):

A few important notes:

- Be careful calling `super` on your `mouseMoved` or similar events, or the cursor might just get reset by the base class implementation.
- Only reset your tracking area when the parent view size changes; if you try to do this by overriding `layout()` it's going to be happening *all the time* which is not great

Here's an example class that you can just use as a base class in your storyboards.

Swift 4 code:

```
import Cocoa

final class MouseTrackingTextView: NSTextView {

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        setupTrackingArea()
    }

    // MARK: - Resizing

    // Call this in your controller's `viewDidLayout`
    // so it only gets called when the view resizes
    func superviewResized() {
        resetTrackingArea()
    }

    // MARK: - Mouse Events

    override func resetCursorRects() {
        addCursorRect(bounds, cursor: cursorType)
    }

    override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
        cursorType.set()
    }

    // MARK: - Private Properties

    private var currentTrackingArea: NSTrackingArea?

    private var cursorType: NSCursor {
        return isEditable ? .iBeam : .pointingHand
    }

    // MARK: - Private API

    private func setupTrackingArea() {
        let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: bounds,
                                          options: [.activeAlways, .mouseMoved],
                                          owner: self, userInfo: nil)
        currentTrackingArea = trackingArea
        addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
    }

    private func resetTrackingArea() {
        if let trackingArea = currentTrackingArea {
            removeTrackingArea(trackingArea)
        }
        setupTrackingArea()
    }

}
```