# incorrect mouse cursor on some view in case view below is TextEditor

Tags: macos, swiftui, mouse-cursor, swiftui-texteditor

```
struct Test: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TextEditor(text: $text)
            
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .padding()
                
        }.padding(50)
    }
}
```

Rectangle filled with green color displayed above the TextEditor. But even of this TextEditor changes mouse cursor to another one in case of mouse hovering Rectangle.

Question: **Why? And how to fix?**

I need:

- default mouse cursor when I am hovering Rectangle.
- "text-selectable" cursor on hovering TextEditor.

[image]

MacOS: Monteray 12.4 (21F79)

Xcode: 13.3 (13E113)

Comment: You can disable TextEditor while it is covered with this green rectangle.

Comment: @Asperi This is simplified sample. In original app textEditor is partially covered by another view and always must be enabled =(

Comment: This is long known problem and originated from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html): "Mouse-moved events (type NSMouseMoved) are always sent to the first responder, not to the view under the mouse.". As far as I know there is no stable solution - NSTextView (which  at backend) has always a priority. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32447739/12299030).